# UK Tourist Visit Visa - Bank Statement Requirement

Tags: visas, uk, applications, proof-provenance-of-funds

I'm applying for a 6-month UK tourist/visit visa as a US permanent resident. Im wondering if 2 months of bank statements—Jan and Feb, both ending within 31 days of my application date, and both showing consistent salary deposits as well as savings withdrawals—are enough to satisfy the proof of fund?

I hesitate to show 3 months or more because my bank statements in October, November and December involve lots of irregular transfers that are all reasonable (big payments for new and existing apartment, then big insurance deposit after new apartment's water damage, and then payment for another new apartment as well as moving there, then transfer of payments from and to roommates since we're all moving together, and lastly deposit returns from the two previous apartments...).

Im afraid if I include bank statements from Dec and Nov and/or older, they'd look suspicious as if i was fund parking or living an unstable lifestyle, and i really have no idea how to compile all these evidence for deposits and insurance and transfers for the application upload... My Jan and Feb statements however look very stable.

Should I add 3-6 months of payslips as well?

Comment: You might review [this question and answer](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/66104/should-i-submit-bank-statements-when-applying-for-a-uk-visa-what-do-they-say-ab). Trying to sanitize your application is unlikely to succeed.

Comment: Thank you. ive actually seen that post... I think i fall under the Erratic/unstable Lifestyle as well as fund parking categories though my balance has never fallen below 0... I guess i'll just have to submit the proofs for those transactions.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have the luxury of choice. If the application asks for 6 months, you have to provide six months. If you give for only two months, you will be denied a visa and will consider future applications as suspicious as in their eyes, you tried to deceive them.

In your case, you have to submit the bank statements truly and fully. In addition to the bank statements, you have to submit a cover letter explaining the funds and possibly a proof (like receipts and all) that shows these come from legit transactions.

Note that the immigration officials may have seen hundreds of applications similar to yours and its not suspicious, unless you make it one.

Comment: Thank you. My application doesn't specifically ask for 6 months, only says evidence of funds which include "financial documents showing that you have sufficient funds available. These must clearly show that you have access to the funds, such as: bank statements." I was concerned about the 6 months because ive seen so many posts saying that one must supply 3-6 months when there's no such requirement on number

Comment: two months is not enough for ascertaining your financials. 6 months is the norm. 3 months may be acceptable, or not.

Comment: I see. thx. Should I then submit 12 months of bank statements to show my stable lifestyle and regular funds before 10/2022? I'll do my best to compile and submit all the evidence for those irregular transactions.

Comment: @hugosimons If you think you need one year of statements to explain, then go ahead. But 6 months is usually enough.